# Multiple queries in excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to use two formulas in one line. The aim is to sum two columns, `A` and `B`, in `C` with two conditions:

First, if cells in `A` or `B` are blank, then formula in column `C` will return blank.
Second, if `B` is greater than `A`, then leave cell blank.

Both formula should be used in the same cell simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (in `C2`):

```
=IF(OR(A2="",B2=""),"",IF(B2>A2,"",SUM(A2:B2)))
```

You can then fill this formula down column `C`.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for 2 numbers with COUNT, e.g.

`=IF((COUNT(A2,B2)=2)*(B2<=A2),A2+B2,"")`